# ASP.net MVC Controller Action - how to prevent redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have the following in my Action:

```
[AjaxException] 
public ActionResult DoSomething(sring someParam1, string someParam2) {

    //do whatever you need to do here, db etc
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

in my html

```
<form id="search-frm" name="search-frm" action="@Url.Action("DoSomething", "MyActions")" method="post" >

    <input type="button" id="search-btn" value="search" class="btn" onclick="DoSomething();return false;" />
    <input type="text" name="param1" id="param1" />
    <input type="text" name="param2" id="param2" />
</form>
```

in my JS

```
function DoSomething() {  
   $("#search-frm").submit();
   return false;
}
```

When I click on the button, and after the controller action `DoSomething` is done, I get redirected to `MyActions/DoSomething`. Is there a way to not have that w/o using jquery `$.ajax`? I simply need to do something and not go away from the existing page.

Comment: Why not use AJAX? Seems like the perfect tool for what you are trying to achieve: submit a form and stay on the same page. I suspect that you have omitted some important details from your question. So please provide them. Currently here's how I interpret your question: `How to watch take a photo without a camera?`. Meaningless.

Comment: that is why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583679/asp-net-mvc-and-ajax-added-performance-overhead

Comment: Then why are you posting meaningless dupes?

Comment: The *meaningless dupe* doesn't contain enough details in order to be answerable. You say that a normal controller action call takes 403ms and an AJAX call to the same action takes 3400ms which is pretty hilarious because an AJAX call is like a normal action call. I guess your measures are a bit off.

Comment: this question or the original? What details do you need?

Comment: I dunno what details I need. For example showing the code in your controller action might be like a good start. And yeah, I am talking about your original question. This one doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The code in my controller action is a long stored procedure call that takes 403ms (negligible amount of time). I can post it, but I don't see how it would help since that is not where the delay is. I do database ops in other controllers that don't use ajax and they are fast. It's quite long, but I can post it, if you think that it is useful. but I repeat - it takes 402ms -> while total ajax call takes 3400ms even when nothing is returned.

Comment: Darin, you misunderstood me. THE INSIDE of the action takes 403ms. But the total ajax when it comes back takes 3400ms, so there is a giant waste of time added between server and client even when nothing is returned.

Comment: And how much time does your controller action take if you invoke it normally? By typing the url of your controller action in the browser address bar for example? Without AJAX? And if you tell me 403ms I have reasons to believe that there's something that you are not telling us correctly :-) It's hard to believe that an AJAX call would take almost 7 times more than a normal action call.

Comment: I haven't tested it because it accepts a SearchCriteria object that needs to be passed. I am not sure how to test it on the browser address.

Comment: I guess I can set the object inside for test purposes. Let me try it out

Comment: You could use a normal form submit. Without AJAX to test it. Also you should be aware that there is an additional overhead to calling a controller action than just the body of the controller action itself. But hardly to believe that it is a factor of 7.

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing. using form submit. It's fast. around 410ms. Believe me, I am just as bewildered as you are.

Comment: No, sorry, I simply don't believe you. You are like claiming that an AJAX call takes 7 times more than a normal synchronous call to the same action. Either you are not telling us all or the way you are measuring your results is wrong. Though to say without you providing a what I call `narrowed down version of your code allowing us to reproduce the problem`.

Comment: What you are asking to do isn't possible with the code you currently are trying to use.  This is the nature of HTTP.  It's stateless.  So when you send a request to the server as a POST, it will try to rebind whatever View and/or Model you for the response -- THUS, eliminating any change to cancel the submit (ie. return false;).

Comment: sure, I can do that, I am not lying to you. There is a huge delay that is preventing me from finishing the project and optimizing the performance to what it should be. Not to mention that server-client issues are notoriously hard to debug. I will post more code, but like I said. It takes 403ms. Not sure where the reast of the delay comes from. My guess is MVC and/or ajax add overhead.

Comment: No, MVC/ajax is definitely not where your overhead comes from, even if you would like it to be so.

Comment: well, I updated the code. If you solve the mystery, you're will be my saviour because I am ready to go back to web services. Never had issues like these before. Hopefully, you understand what I am asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because your code is so. When you click on the button you are calling the `DoSomething` javascript function and inside that you are submitting the form. So it is same as the normal form submit(clicking on the submit button to submit). that is the reason it is redirecting (actually being posted to `DoSomething` action.

If you do not want to navigate away from the current page, you may use `ajax` to do your posting and get result and stay in the same page. So i would make changes to your code like this

**1)** Get rid of the OnClick event binding from the HTML markup

**2)** Add this javascript which handles the form submit

```
$(function(){
  $("#search-frm").submit(e){

   e.preventDefault();  // prevent the default form posting. Let's stay here
   $.post("@Url.Action("DoSomething","MyActions")",$("#search-frm").serialize(), function(data){
          //do something with the response data 
   });

  });     
});
```

Not sure why return `EmptyResult` from the Action method. You may need to return some valid response which indicates the status of the Action you are trying to perform.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string param1,string param2)
{
  //do something 
   return Json(new 
             { Status= true,
               Message="Succesfully saved"
             });      
}
```

You may keep a generic `ViewModel` to return such results and use that, instead of dynamically typing like above.

```
public class OperationStatus
{
  public bool Status  { set;get;}
  public string Message { set;get;}
}
```

and in your action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string param1,string param2)
{
  //do something 
  var res=new OperationStatus();
  res.Status=true;
  res.Message="Successfully Added";
   return Json(res);      
}
```

Comment: how about not using $.ajax at all?

Comment: $.post is a short form of $.ajax with Action method type as POST. I think that is enough for this scenario. You may also use that as well.

Comment: How can one evaluate the JSON response on the client ?

Comment: Please post it as a seperate question with the JSON format you are receiving